# MailPress Child Themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, newsletter

I found the solution, so I'll post this in case anyone else is looking for this info.

I was looking into using a child theme with MailPress (the Wordpress newsletter plugin).

I created the following folder:

```
public/mysite/wp-content/plugins/mailpress/mp-content/themes/twentyten-child
```

But when I went to the Admin->Mails->Themes page to activate this child theme, it showed the error:

> The parent theme is missing. Please install the "twentyten-child"
>   parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to insert the following comments at the top of the child theme's style.css file:

```
/*
 Theme Name:     twentyten Child Theme
 Template:       twentyten
 Version:        0.1
*/
```